# Javascript - Troubles with looping through array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm making a quiz that displays how many questions you got right. I have managed to get it to work with the first question but i'm struggling to figure out how to loop through all the other questions within my array.

here's my JS code:

```
var questionArray = new Array (8);
questionArray [0] = "q1"
questionArray [1] = "q2"
questionArray [2] = "q3"
questionArray [3] = "q4"
questionArray [4] = "q5"
questionArray [5] = "q6"
questionArray [6] = "q7"
questionArray [7] = "q8"



var correctAnswers = 0;

function checkQuestions()
{
    var questions = document.getElementsByName(questionArray[0]);
    var numberOfRadios = questions.length;

    for( var i = 0; i < numberOfRadios; i++)
    {
        if(questions[i].checked)
        {
            if(questions[i].value == "correct")
            {
                correctAnswers++
            }
        }       
    }   
document.getElementById("correctAnswers").innerHTML = "You got:" + "<br>" + correctAnswers + "/8!!";
}
```

Comment: Please use an array literal it's easier and has a better performance.

`var questionsArray = ["q1", "q2", "q3"]` and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`questionArray[0]` returns "q1".

If you have only one element of that name, then `questions.length` will equal 1.

Thus, your `for` loop will only iterate once.

What you want to do, is this:

```
function checkQuestions()
{
    for( var i = 0; i < questionArray.length; i++)
    {
        //I assume you have only one question per name, if not then you need id
        var question = document.getElementsByName(questionArray[i])[0];
        if(question.checked)
        {
            if(question.value == "correct")
            {
                correctAnswers++;
            }
        }       
    }   
    document.getElementById("correctAnswers").innerHTML = "You got:" + "<br>" + correctAnswers + "/8!!";
}
```

Comment: I guess what he calls questions is a set of input radio (answer) with the same name for each question

Answer (score 0):

Loop through questions as well..

```
function checkQuestions()
{
    for (var j = 0; j < questionArray.length; j++)
       var questions = document.getElementsByName(questionArray[j]);
       ...
    }

 document.getElementById("correctAnswers").innerHTML = "You got:" + "<br>" + correctAnswers + "/8!!";
}
```